# XCode 6 shows no files after commit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, cocoa

I have a project. I have two branches, master and development. I've committed everything in development branch. I've gone to master branch and it showed me empty project. Going back to development branch, again now it is showing me no files at all. I'm using Cocoa pods so I have Pods target within my project and I'm opening my project clicking on *ProjectName.xcworkspace* beacuse of Cocoa pods. How to see my files in my project again?

**EDIT:** I've tried to run *pod install* again and now, when opening .xcworkspace, it shows my project target for 2 seconds and then it disappears and XCode only shows Pods target.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the square icon next to the search field in the bottom of project navigator?

Comment: Yes, nothing. Navigator only shows me breakpoints map.

Comment: I can see my files when I load ProjectName.xcodeproj and Pods.xcodeproj. But nothin on .xcworkspace

Comment: I've done now pod install. I am only seeing now Pods target

Comment: I am having the same issue.